# Extract static member type from class of local variable

Tags: c++, static-members

Is it possible to extract a static member type from the class of a local variable? aka something in the lines of

```
class A {
 public:
  typedef int constituent_type;
  constituent_type a;
  A(constituent_type _a) :a(_a) {};
}


int main() {
  auto a = A(42);

  // ... lots ... of other code; where I have long since forgottten, what the type of a really was

  std::max<a::constituent_type>(a, a); //<<<
}
```

Comment: `std::max` will deduce the type of it's arguments and use `operator<` to compare them - so I am unclear as to what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Please post an example of a situation where you actually need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in C++ 11 or later using `decltype`:

```
decltype(a)::x
```

Live demo:

https://godbolt.org/z/cTq9zhKxe